# error: Macro % has illegal name (%define)

Tags: shell-script, variable-substitution, bash-expansion

I have a build support script for building my packages. Now I want to automatically set the Version in my spec files. I use the macro `%{auto_version}` for that. In my script I want to invoke `rpmbuild -D 'auto_version 1.1' packet.spec` for example.

```
#!/bin/bash
version=$(version.sh)
#snip
define="'auto_version ${version}'"

build_spec () {
    spec=$1
    define=$2
    #snip
    build_output=$(rpmbuild -D "$define" $spec)
    # snip
}

build_spec $build_spec "$define"
```

However this generates the error `error: Macro % has illegal name (%define)`

I've tried different escaping, quoting and making `define` an array, handled with `${define[@]}`.

Comment: version.sh correctly outputs a version number e.g. 0.1

Comment: Basically copied from my answer to your previous, now-deleted question: pretty sure you really want `define="auto_version ${version}"` without the single quotes (though not familiar with RPM; but requiring literal quotes in the value would be very weird indeed).

Answer (score 2):

As @tripleee right points, the reason of `error: Macro % has illegal name (%define)` is extra quotes in `-D|--define` directives like:

```
-D "\"_gpg_name $gpgname\""
```

the right version is:

```
-D "_gpg_name $gpgname"
```